# When is it appropriate to use g.query()...vertex() vs g.V.has()

Tags: gremlin, titan

I'm a little confused about this one. Several similar examples can be found throughout the documentation. Such as :

```
g.V.has('name','hercules').next()
g.query().has("name",EQUAL,"hercules").vertices()
```

Could someone clarify what the difference in the process is between the two above?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first is gremlin-groovy syntax:

```
g.V.has('name','hercules').next()
```

and either iterates all vertices looking for vertices that have a "name" property with a value of "hercules".  In the event that "name" is indexed then titan will utilize the index to avoid the linear scan to find such vertices.

The second is basically Java and the Titan API.  The above gremlin-groovy code basically compiles down to your second statement:

```
g.query().has("name",EQUAL,"hercules").vertices()
```

however, in the case of the second statement it returns an iterator of all vertices that match the filter and doesn't just pop off the first one as shown in the gremlin statement (given the use of next()).

Comment: Thanks! So the first compiles down to the second. Which explains why we would need to use g.query() in some instances for more control over complex index searches (ie: ordered traversal/labels/etc)?

Comment: the second is also compatible with the blueprints api so you are abstracted ok.